I mistakenly erased Macintosh HD and am now stuck at macOS Utilities screen. How to fix?
I mistakenly erased Macintosh HD and now both the Recovery disk and Macintosh HD are combined.
Unable to reinstall the macOS as it doesn’t find any core volume:



Can you help me with the commands to get back the lost Macintosh HD partition and reinstall macOS?

Boot into Internet Recovery Mode:
Restart your Mac and hold down Cmd + Option + R until you see a spinning globe. This will boot your Mac into Internet Recovery Mode, which downloads the recovery tools from Apple’s servers.

Also you may have to create a volume on your internal HDD. Personally I would make the whole thing one big volume and let macOS do any further configuring (depending on which OS version) that it needs. I have seen Internet Recovery fail if there are no volumes to install on, even though it should create them during installation.
